# Node.js ECMAScript 2015 - var vs let

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Now that ECMAScript 2015 (or ES6) has a wider support in Node.js as well I have seen a few examples where people started to use the `let` keyword when requiring packages. I wonder what is the difference (if any) or what is the recommended way or working with packages in ES6 & Node.js.

Essentially what's the difference between:

```
var express = require('express');`
```

and

```
let express = require('express');`
```

Comment: Without the wider context, there's no difference between those two lines.

Comment: That's what I thought @JamesThorpe as well - I thought that maybe there are some 'best practices' that come out lately that I have potentially missed.

Comment: *"what is the recommended way"* I'd use `const` (since I assume you don't want to reassign imports anyway).

Comment: I'm not saying there is _no_ difference, but how they differ depends on exactly where and how those lines are present in a source file.